# Skewness and two-tailed hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, skewness

I have a particular question of which I am unsure of the answer:

"Using illustrative examples, explain the role of skewness of a statistical distribution in a two-tailed hypothesis test."

My initial thought is that a skewed distribution is by definition not normally distributed so would mean that the test result is in accurate?

Couldn't find anything in lecture material/notes, so thought I would ask the question directly. Any help would be appreciated.